# How to get the selected value of @html.dropdownlist here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having this on my client side console

[image]

I want to extract only 2015 which is currently selected option.
How is it possible?

Comment: `$('#YearIn option:selected').text()`

Comment: You need to put the code in the question, not an image of it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED**

According to [this](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/) link,

```
$( "#YearIn option:selected" ).text();
```

This should do.

Comment: The first one will return `1` (not `2015`)

Comment: I was just trying... I am very new to this

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
var selectedOptionText = $("YearIn option:selected").text();
```

For instance check the following snippet:

```js
$(function(){
  $("#YearIn").change(function(){
    alert($("#YearIn option:selected").text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="YearIn">
  <option val="1">One</option>
  <option val="2">Two</option>
  <option val="3">Three</option>
  <option val="4" selected>Four</option>
  <option val="5">Five</option>
</select>
```